# Error de token en gs Appscript

Tags: java

```java
function doPost (e) {

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet ();  

  var payload = JSON.parse (e.postData.Contents);

  var RowContents = [];

  var encabezados = ActiveSheet.getRange («A1:A1») .getDataRegion () .getValues ()[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {

    var header = encabezados[i];

    var deep = header.toString () .split (».»);

    var dataVal = carga útil [«leads»][0];

    para (var j = 0; j < deep.length; j++) {

      var d = profundidad[j];

      DataVal = DataVal[d];

    }

    RowContents.push (DataVal);

  }
}
```

hoja `activa.AppendRow(contenido de la fila);`

devuelve «OK»;

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola Juan Pablo, bienvenido, primero edita tu pregunta y cambia la etiqueta, esto no es java, por otro lado cual es el error?, por favor, indica que esperas que haga el programa , y que hace para poder ayudarte, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.